# axlsx conditional formatting for letters / words

Tags: axlsx

I want to style the background color of an axlsx created sheet based upon cell content that is a word (ie. 'Pass' or 'Fail')

I can format the sheet if the cell content is a number.  I've tried changed type => :containsText and adding :text => "Fail" but with no success.  I can change the cell content to 'Fail' easily, but then I cannot get the conditional styling to work.

This is the code that works great if the cell values are numbers (in this case 2):

```
 red =  styles.add_style(:bg_color=> 'FFFF0000', :type => :dxf)



# Apply conditional formatting to range I:L in the worksheet
sheet.add_conditional_formatting('I:L', { :type => :cellIs,
                                          :operator => :equal,
                                          :formula => "2",
                                          :dxfId => red,
                                          :priority => 1 })
```

But if I change the :formula => "Fail" then it doesn't work.  I've tried changing :type => containsText and a bunch of combinations.

Answer (score 4):

Took some more fiddling around, but here's the answer :)

```
red =  styles.add_style(:bg_color=> 'FFFF0000', :type => :dxf)
sheet.add_conditional_formatting('I:L', { :type => :containsText, 
                                      :text => "Fail",
                                      :operator => :equal,
                                      :dxfId => red,
                                      :priority => 1 })
```

Comment: Thank you.   I would upvote you, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @PauloSteinitch If the answer was correct, you could always Accept it instead of upvote :) Cheers!

Comment: I'm pretty sure I tried that and it didn't work.  I eventually moved on and used ruby to conditionally assign a style that was defined elsewhere.

Comment: Hmm, maybe we're using different versions of axlsx.. Im using axlsx-2.0.0, and it works pretty well. I even sent them a PR to include an exampe of this in the repo.